# @Html.DropDownListFor Basic Usage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm just starting to learn MVC4 and I must admit I'm a little challenged by all the reliance on lambda expressions, generics and anonymous types, especially when there are many overloaded functions. It's a bit confusing to try and understand how the HTML Helpers work. Take the "DropDownListFor" Helper, for example. I tried to extract the essentials from my code. That's why you see only a only a single column, "Gender", in the table. Hopefully it is still syntactically correct:

```
@model IEnumerable<BusinessLayer.Employee>
<table>
    @foreach (var employee in Model) 
    {    
        <tr>
            <td>
            @{

                var listItems = new List<SelectListItem>()
                {
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "Male",   Value = "M"},
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "Female", Value = "F"}
                };

                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => employee.Gender, listItems, listItems.Find(i => i.Value == employee.Gender).Text)                          
            }  

            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

There are two Employees in the Model object, an IEnumerable of Employee and the following HTML is generated

```
<table> 
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="employee_Gender" name="employee.Gender"><option value="">Male</option>
                <option value="M">Male</option>
                <option value="F">Female</option>
            </select>
    </tr>       
        </td>    
             <select id="employee_Gender" name="employee.Gender"><option value="">Female</option>
                <option value="M">Male</option>
                <option value="F">Female</option>
             </select>                
        </td>
</table>
```

Looking at the first param of the DropDownListFor Method,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => employee.Gender, ...
```

...Do I understand correctly that the "m" represents the instance of the model class that was passed into the View? In the online examples that I have seen, I have seen examples where the "m" appears to refer to the model class but where the model is a single instance class, for example, a single Employee object, rather than a collection of Employees as is the case here where I want to display a table list of Employees. I'm assuming that the intent of the first param of the DropDownListFor Method is "point/bind' to a *property* in the model, so that's why I made m => employee.Gender. Is this what I should be doing when the model is a collection of Employees rather than a single Employee? If so, I am confused as to how I can generate unique IDs for the two drop down lists which were both assigned "employee_Gender" for both the NAME and ID attributes.

For the 3rd parameter of the Helper DropDownListFor,

```
listItems.Find(i => i.Value == employee.Gender).Text
```

Is this reasonable? The value for employee.Gender is either "M" or "F" but the display Text is "Male" and "Female." I am confused whether this param is used to specify a default "NO SELECT" first value or whether this param is used to select from the drop down the value of the current Employee---or perhaps it can do both? For example, does it select the *Text* specified if found and otherwise add the text specified as the *FIRST?* parameter if the value is not found? That appears to be how it works from what I see. Can this 3rd param be simplified or is my example reasonable?

Thanks for your patience in reading my many flurry of questions in trying to better understand this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688910/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlistfor-with-model-of-type-liststring

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146204/how-to-use-mvc-html-helper-dropdownlistfor-with-an-enum

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Part 1: Explaining Lambda magic

You're not alone. Lambdas + MVC make coding wicked easy, but they also make it seem rather magical (due to the abstraction).

> Looking at the first param of the DropDownListFor Method [...] Do I understand correctly that the "m" represents the instance of the model class that was passed into the View?

Yes.

HTML Helpers + Lambdas in Razor are simple and magical because they are taking a shortcut and not actually revealing to you what's going on.

First, let's take a look at `@Html`. We know `@` begins our Razor syntax and then `Html` is magic. Actually, `Html` is an [HtmlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) object that is automatically initialised and given to you. More specifically it's an `HtmlHelper<TModel>`. The Razor HTML editor is smart and knows ahead of time what type TModel will be based on what you've said this view's model type is. That's why you have so much intellisense.

When you type

```
@model IEnumerable<BusinessLayer.Employee>
```

The editor reads that and makes an assumption now that the HTML Helper will be `HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<BusinessLayer.Employee>>`. When it comes time to compile the page, the HTML helper will in fact be that type (of course).

So what about `DropDownListFor` or any other extension method?

Looking at [DropDownListFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703573%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) we can see that it's actually `DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>`. We now understand that TModel is our view's model type. `DropDownListFor` knows about this because the method is **extending** `HtmlHelper<TModel>`. Therefore DropDownListFor knows that the incoming type is whatever type is defined at the top of the view. What about `TProperty`?

`TProperty` is the return type. That's the type that you specify when you select your property. The view gives HtmlHelper the model type, who then gives DropDownListFor the model type and now that you're in a lambda expression: `(x => x.Property)` you select the property which then selects the type for you; in this case a **string** (Gender).

## Part 2: Your problem

It's hard to answer your question without knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve. Do you have a collection of Employees and you want to display multiple gender dropdown boxes for each and then save them?

When dealing with collections it's a little more tricky, since MVC doesn't handle them well out of the box; it's usually best to write your own solutions according to what you need done.

I don't really like the idea of a single view getting a collection of things on a page. Consider this piece of logic:

### Your way:

- Get collection of Employees
- Give Employees to a view
- Have view create a single SelectListItem
- Loop through and display the SelectList for each Employee

### My way

- Get collection of Employees
- Give employees to a view
- Have the view loop through and pass each Employee to another view (partial)
- Each partial deals with a single Employee

With MVC do try to break things down into small, logical parts. Views should be stupid; meaning they shouldn't really do any logic or thinking. Things become easier this way and it makes sure that your views don't grow into monsters.

### Example solution walk-through

Try this:

Create a new PartialView called _*EmployeeGender.cshtml* in the same folder as the view you're using.

Use this code

**_EmployeeGender.cshtml**

```
@model BusinessLayer.Employee

<tr>
    <td>
    @{

        var listItems = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem {Text = "Male",   Value = "M"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "Female", Value = "F"}
        };

        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, listItems, string.Empty)
    }  

    </td>
</tr>
```

**Your original view**

```
@model IEnumerable<BusinessLayer.Employee>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Employees";
}

<h2>Employees</h2>

<table>
    @foreach (var employee in Model) 
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("_EmployeeGender", employee);
    }
</table>
```

### Results

Let's have a look at our **generated HTML** now:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
<select id="Gender" name="Gender"><option value=""></option>
<option selected="selected" value="M">Male</option>
<option value="F">Female</option>
</select>  

    </td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>
<select id="Gender" name="Gender"><option value=""></option>
<option value="M">Male</option>
<option selected="selected" value="F">Female</option>
</select>  

    </td>
</tr></table>
```

We can see that there is now a blank selection and that our dropdown boxes are automatically selected with the Employee's values (I create one male and one female employee).

**Do Note** that the `id` and `name` HTML attributes are the same. If you want to submit a form with these values then it will require more work. But this is a reasonable starting point for you.

Comment: a very good answer, I have been struggling with the same concept myself, the partial view solution is very interesting. How would saving gender changes to several employees work when using partial views?

Comment: Partials can have some secret gotchas when dealing with forms, as MVC generates the ID from the hierarchy of the viewmodel. E.g. the id of each `<select>` element is `Gender`, which is wrong when it comes to HTML and model binding when you submit the form. You are better off using EditorTemplates, which natively understands enumerables and will automatically index your arrays for you, and when you post the form again it will bind it correctly. Look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx

Comment: Agreed. My preference is usually towards editor and display templates too. I suggest that the OP ask another more specific question after giving it a go if you still need help.

Comment: Awesome answer. I am indebted to you for such thoughtful and well explained response.

Comment: Excellent explaination Rowan ..!
Descriptive yet easy example in the last, won the bet for me. Thanks.