# Using model objects in cshtml file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am a newbie to MVC 4, (after 10 yrs of webforms) and have a question that I have not been able to figure out.
When writing code in the cshtml file, I am walking through a tutorial that has the following line:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
```

What does the `model => model.City` imply? Why can't I use `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model.City)` ? I understand this is Linq query, but I would like to understand why would I need the `model goes to model.city` ?

Comment: Selman22 answered before I could, but if you want some further reading on a similar topic, feel free to check out [Explaining Lambda magic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720327/html-dropdownlistfor-basic-usage/19720798#19720798).

Comment: Thanks @Rowan. The more I study MVC & EF, the more confused I get :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, that is called a [*lambda expression*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).In your scenario, you are telling the `DisplayNameFor` method that *"take my model, and create a display element for this property."*.You can't use `model.City`, because it just returns the value of the property.The method needs more than that in order to create a display element for your property.For example, it needs to know it's type and also it's attributes (like [`DisplayName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute.aspx) attribute) and then it creates a display element for your element(it should be label I guess) .

`DisplayName` method is doing that using [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx).The method takes an `Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>` and uses it to get the name, value and the metadata information (attributes) about your property.

If you want to use `model.City` you can still use it, but then you won't need the functionality that `DisplayNameFor` provides.If you just need to display value of the property you can always do it like this:

```
<label> @model.City </label>
```

> I understand this is Linq query,

Btw, this is incorrect, that is not a `LINQ` query.That is just an extension method.