# Razor HTML Helper Class - can't access Standard HTML Helpers

Tags: razor, html-helper

I'm trying to create a HTML helper for displaying a dropdown box in a certain way.

I've started to create one like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace uQuiz.WebUI
{
    public static class HtmlHelpers
    {

        public static  MvcHtmlString TimerMinuteSelectBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
        where TModel : class
        {
            // Error, no definition
            htmlHelper.DropDownBoxFor();
        }
    }
}
```

But `htmlHelper` doesn't contain a definition for `DropDownBoxFor()` or any other standard Html Helpers such as `TextBoxFor()`

> Error 1   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a
>   definition for 'DropDownBoxFor' and no extension method
>   'DropDownBoxFor' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

I see that they are able to access it in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16089427/894792 but I can't.

How can I get access to the standard HTML helpers in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16089427/894792).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to `System.Web.Mvc.Html`

```
public static  MvcHtmlString TimerMinuteSelectBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, ....
{
  MvcHtmlString dropdown = SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(helper, expression, ....
```