# Html.DropDownList does not populate 'selected' in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

This code worked (correctly reflected the user's current timezone) back in the aspx version.

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("User.TimeZone", AppHelper.GetUSTimeZones(Model.TimeZone))%>
```

In switching to Razor I'm finding that the rendered control does not place the user's timezone as the selected item.

I've reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656758/mvc3-razor-dropdownlistfor-enums) and see that others have experienced the same issue. Shouldn't I expect HtmlHelpers to work the same when moving to Razor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the overload of DropDownList you are using, the method takes a string for the field name and an IEnumerable of SelectListItem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist.aspx

So your AppHelper.GetUSTimeZones(Model.TimeZone)) needs to return IEnumerable<SelectListItem>.

To make an option selected you need to indicate that the SelectListItem is the selected one. So something like:

```
_timeZoneRepo.RetrieveAll().Select(t => new SelectListItem { Text = t.Name, Value = t.Id, Selected = TimeZone.Id == t.Id ? true : false });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's more complex than i'd like it to be but I suppose that's the price of tooling up. In the longer run (e.g. then next time i need it) it (better) pay off. thx