# DropDownListFor enum doesn't bind back to the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

On my MVC form, I need to bind a drop down box to an enumeration on my ViewModel.  The best way I found to do that is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8538813/356544).

It appeared to work at first, but now that I've added validation to my form, I've discovered it does not bind back to the ViewModel.

Here's my razor code:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.response, 
                          new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Vouchers.Models.ResponseType))),
                          "Please Select")
</div>
```

And here's my view model definition for the field:

```
[DisplayName("Response")]
[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "You must select a response before submitting this form.")]
public ResponseType response { get; set; }
```

The problem is that I cannot submit the form; even after selecting a response from my drop down, the Validation error message for the Range attribute is displayed and the client side validation prevents the form from submitting.

I believe this is because the SelectList for the drop down contains only the string names of the enum, not the underlying integer value.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you need a `Range` attribute when you know the range you are binding too and already have `Required` ?

Comment: The Required attribute doesn't seem to be work on its own--the response field defaults to the value 0.  Actually I could just take Required out, it seems to have no effect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create Dictionary where Key will be integer representation of the enum and string- the name of enum.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.response, 
                      new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Vouchers.Models.ResponseType)).OfType<Vouchers.Models.VoucherResponseType>().ToDictionary(x => Convert.ToInt32(x), y => y.ToString()), "Key", "Value"), "Please Select")
```

Sorry for possible errors, I have not tried it.

Comment: Thanks this worked!  Although it turned out a cast was needed in order to go from the System.Array returned by Enum.GetValues to the IEnumerable needed by ToDictionary.  I suggested an edit to this effect.