# Drop Down List item with enum values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

i have an enum class

```
public enum Language {
    English = 0,
    Malayalam=1
}
```

i want to put the string in dropdown list and store the value in database when inserted. And i also declare it in property list as

```
public Language Language { get; set; }
```

how can i access these in dropdown list(MVC4)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Search before asking: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=DropDownlist+enum

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656758/mvc3-razor-dropdownlistfor-enums/8538813#8538813

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx check this