# How do I call the following function?

Tags: c#, generics

How do I call this function?

```
public static HtmlString DropdownForEnum<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Type type,
    string name, string optionLabel, object htmlAttributes)
```

Comment: What a useful comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside a page (using the razor syntax):

```
@Html.DropDownForEnum(typeof(enumToDropDown), name: "Foo", optionLable: "Bar", htmlAttributes: null)
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me a direct answer without bashing.

Answer (score 2):

The "this" part of the arguments indicates to me that that's an "extension method" - basically a helper method that does some public operations on an object, but can be called as though it's a method of that object.

```
HtmlHelper<Model> helper;
Type type;
String name;
String optionLabel;
Object htmlAttributes;

helper.DropdownForEnum(type, name, optionLabel, htmlAttributes);
// or, the standard way for calling a static:
NameOfClassWhereYouFoundMethod.DropdownForEnum(helper, type, name, optionLabel, htmlAttributes);
```

Comment: except that the function has a static declaration, so it wouldn't be called on an instance of HtmlHelper.

Comment: @MikeCorcoran All extension methods are declared statically, because the instance of HtmlHelper is specified as an argument. (this HtmlHelper...)

Comment: ugh, brainfart. you're right, i was thinking only the outer class declaration had to be static

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension method on HtmlHelper.
As so, it should be called like this:

```
HtmlHelper<TModel> instance = new HtmlHelper<TModel>();
instance.DropdownForEnum(type, name, optionLabel, htmlAttributes)
```

where TModel is the type assigned to the generic at the moment of declaration.

Please see also this question:
[MVC3 Razor DropDownListFor Enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656758/mvc3-razor-dropdownlistfor-enums)

About Extension Methods, please see this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is an `extension` method on **HtmlHelper**. You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx).

You can call it lke this

```
 yourhtmlHelperObject.DropdownForEnum(someType,someName,label,attributes);
```