# MVC DropdownListFor Enum with int value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, enums, html.dropdownlistfor

Ok, so this is an issue that has bothered me since the first time I started playing with MVC around 3 years ago.
Binding to dropdownlists has always been a pain in the arse but there is a neat way to do it for enums by doing this:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(mediaZone.Common.Models.AssetType)), Model.Type))
```

Great, but the only problem is that that solution will output something like this:

```
<select id="Type" name="Type">
    <option>Image</option>
    <option selected="selected">Video</option>
    <option>Website</option>
</select>
```

What I would like to do is output something like this:

```
<select id="Type" name="Type">
    <option value="1">Image</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Video</option>
    <option value="3">Website</option>
</select>
```

We are on version 5 now of MVC, you would think that many many many people have had this issue and don't want to write code to fix it.
I really hope someone out there has a **one line** solution to this niggling issue of mine :)

Cheers,
/r3plica

Comment: Have you visted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656758/mvc3-razor-dropdownlistfor-enums

Comment: not what I am looking for. I don't want a helper class, I don't even want to write any more code that one line. I know I "could" write a helper class myself, but surely, something this simple should just be a part of MVC....

Comment: So... you need to know if there is a 1 line solution to your problem... that is all your question?   Then: NO.  The line counting thing, back to adolescence time :)

Comment: seems strange that I can create a dropdown list based off my enum in one line, but I can't specify a default value as well.....

Answer (score 1):

Do it in the controller, it is just a foreach for your enum items, returning a collection with 2 values instead of just the name.

Then... in your view you can get a one line of code, far cleaner that the one you have now:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, Model.MySelectList)
```

Other benefits of doing the foreach, is that you could need internationalization in the names of each Enum item, so you could do the translation during the foreach.