# MVC @Html.DropDownList - Default Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a list which I created in the controller:

```
    var PayList = new[] {  
                  new ListEntry { Id = 1, Name = "" },       
                  new ListEntry { Id = 2, Name = "Yes" },         
                  new ListEntry { Id = 3, Name = "No" }          

                };

    ViewBag.PayList = new SelectList(PayList, "Id", "Name",2);
```

In the View I have the following:

```
    @Html.DropDownList("Pay", ViewBag.PayList as SelectList)
```

I was expecting the above to default to Yes but did not happen(Note that I am passing 2 in the ViewBag.PayList.

Comment: What version of MVC? Your example code works fine for me in MVC3.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410543/dropdownlist-setting-selected-item-in-asp-net-mvc/2410614#2410614.

Comment: This should work fine. In fact it worked fine when I tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is sound, but I think in order for the scope of the controller to appropriately communicate with your view, you need to do the:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PayList)
```

Actually... here's a good article: [dropdownlist set selected value in MVC3 Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807256/dropdownlist-set-selected-value-in-mvc3-razor)

Don't use the ViewBag... get familiar with creating ViewModels.