# DropDownList helper doesn't see selected

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, view, html-helper, html-select

My code from the View is:

```
@Html.DropDownList("subsidiary", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Subsidiaries, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "chzn-select" }, { "style", "width: 230px;" } });
```

ViewBag.Subsidiaries contains list of SelectListItem with Selected value set to True for the second object. When dropdown list gets rendered in the View no option element has selected assigned to it. Any idea why?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410543/dropdownlist-setting-selected-item-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the name of the parameter and everything works fine!