# MVC DropDownlist not showing selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-select

I am working with MVC and trying to show dropdownlist with some value selected.

```
 ViewData["History"] = new List<SelectListItem>() { new SelectListItem() { Text = "Never", Value = "-1" }, new SelectListItem() { Selected=true, Text = "7", Value = "7"},
                                            new SelectListItem(){ Text="14", Value="14"},new SelectListItem(){ Text="Forever", Value="999"}};
```

And in my View code

```
<p>
<label>History</label>
<%= System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList(Html, "History", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)(ViewData["History"])) %>
</p>
```

Dropdown is rendered correctly, but selected value is not shown. First option is selected by default.

How to make selected option work ?

Answer (score 3):

After writing this question I was looking for answers. But I found this post : [DropDownList setting selected item in asp.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410543/dropdownlist-setting-selected-item-in-asp-net-mvc)

And then I tried making change as re-naming ViewData["History"] to ViewData["HistoryData"] and all of a sudden everything works as expected.

The name of select list and ViewData key should be different.