# MVC DropDownList NOT setting selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, enums, html.dropdownlistfor, selected

I have a View for an Update operation, and I have a `enum` property of my Model:

```
public enum DeliveryStatusType
{
    Active = 1,
    Deactive = 2,
}
```

Basically, I populate the `enum` and using a `DropDownList`. To understand what is going on, I simplified it and posted here as simple as possible.

I've tried both `Html.DropDownList` and `Html.DropDownListFor` and here are the Views:

**1st example (not setting the selected here)**:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DeliveryStatus, new SelectListItem[] {
        new SelectListItem { 
            Selected = false, 
            Text = "Active Delivery", 
            Value = "1" },
        new SelectListItem { 
            Selected = true, 
            Text = "Deactive Delivery", 
            Value = "2" }}) //Notice that I manually set the 2nd true
```

**2nd example (not setting the selected here)**:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DeliveryStatus", new SelectListItem[] {
        new SelectListItem { 
            Selected = false, 
            Text = "Active Delivery", 
            Value = "1" },
        new SelectListItem { 
            Selected = true, 
            Text = "Deactive Delivery", 
            Value = "2" }}) //Notice that I manually set the 2nd true
```

But, what I realized is that when I set the name and the id of the `SELECT` html element **other than** `DeliveryStatus` (lets say `DeliveryStatus1`), it magically works!

**3rd example (Setting the selected here)**:

```
@Html.DropDownList("DeliveryStatus1", new SelectListItem[] {
        new SelectListItem { 
            Selected = false, 
            Text = "Active Delivery", 
            Value = "1" },
        new SelectListItem { 
            Selected = true, 
            Text = "Deactive Delivery", 
            Value = "2" }}) //Notice that I manually set the 2nd true
```

But when I do that and set as `DeliveryStatus1`, I **cannot post** the data to the `Controller`.

What is wrong with this or what am I doing wrong? 
I need both to be able to SET THE SELECTED data and POST it back

Comment: Set the value of property `DeliveryStatus` to `DeliveryStatusType.Deactive`

Comment: possible duplicate of [DropDownList setting selected item in asp.net MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410543/dropdownlist-setting-selected-item-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I assume you wanted me to like "<option value="DeliveryStatus.Deactive">Deactive Delivery</option>". But none of DropDownListFor or DropDownList worked with this

Comment: You are right Richard, but I did the same there, still not functioning properly.

Comment: No. The selected value of `@Html.DropDownListFor` is based on the value of the property, not the value of the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem`. Also I suggest you look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388483/how-do-you-create-a-dropdownlist-from-an-enum-in-asp-net-mvc) for creating an extension method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Stephen Muecke, for `enums` I gave the value as `Enum.ToString()` instead of the Integer value.:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DeliveryStatus, new SelectListItem[] {
        new SelectListItem { 
            Selected = false, 
            Text = "Active Delivery", 
            Value = "Active" },
        new SelectListItem { 
            Selected = true, 
            Text = "Deactive Delivery", 
            Value = "Deactive" }})
```

Comment: Note you don't need the set the `Selected` property in `SelectListItem`. If the value of `model.DeliveryStatus` is `DeliveryStatusType.Deactive` then the 2nd option will be selected hwne the view is displayed.

Comment: I am not manually setting in my actual project. Instead, I use `EnumDropDownListFor` which foreach within the enum class. But to simplify my problem I first wrote the code I posted above and start examining it.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was to make sure the model.Xyz variable was a string and then using the "Selected = true" to make it the default selected value.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TopN, new SelectListItem[]
{
    new SelectListItem() { Text = "10", Value = "10", Selected = false },
    new SelectListItem() { Text = "20", Value = "20", Selected = false },
    new SelectListItem() { Text = "50", Value = "50", Selected = true },
    new SelectListItem() { Text = "100", Value = "100", Selected = false },
    new SelectListItem() { Text = "500", Value = "500", Selected = false }
})
```